# Can JavaScript constructor return function and keep inheritance?

Tags: javascript, oop, function, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

```
function F() {
    return function() {
        return {};
    }
}

var f = new F();
f instanceof F; // returns false
```

As far as I understand, if I want `instanceof` to work, I need to return `this` from the constructor. But I want the constructor to return a function, and I cannot assign to `this`.

So, is this really impossible or can it be done somehow, for `f = new F()` to return a function and still `f instanceof F` to return true?

Comment: You can return a function, since a function is an object. But obviously, `f instanceof F` would not be true, since it is not true.

Comment: Felix: The same way that tautologies are tautological? :)

Comment: Why do you want instanceof to work? It's generally considered harmful.

Comment: The question remains: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: It seems that there's no need to return this from the constructor in order for the instanceof to work. see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ukttM/) for an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function F() {
    var r = function() {
        return {};
    };

    r.__proto__ = this.__proto__;
    return r;
}

var f = new F();
f instanceof F;
true
f();
Object
```

Only works in the browsers with `__proto__`

Answer (score 5):

You could of course make all functions appear to be `instanceof F` by setting `F.prototype = Function.prototype;`.

Unfortunately it looks as if ECMAScript doesn't allow you to create a function subclass.

You can however do it in Gecko using the deprecated `__proto__` property:

```
function F() {
    function f() {
        return {};
    }
    f.__proto__ = F.prototype;
    return f;
 }
 F.prototype.__proto__ = F.__proto__;
```

Comment: Esailia was faster, hence his answer accepted. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sixtease Fair enough, but note that his answer as written won't let you e.g. `.apply` or `.call` on his object, because he doesn't have the extra line that I do.

Comment: @Neil, what exactly F.prototype.__proto__ = F.__proto__; is doing? What would happen if I don't do it?

Comment: @esp Sorry, I can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming across this today, with ES6/2015 there's new syntax you can use to avoid the deprecated `__proto__` property; `Object.setPrototypeOf`. Note that [MDN warns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) that this is a slow/expensive operation.

```
function F() {
    const f = function() {
        return {};
    }
    Object.setPrototypeOf(f, F.prototype);
    return f;
}

var f = new F();
f instanceof F; // returns true
f(); // returns {}
```

Note also that it gets a little weird if you want to initialize values in the constructor. You need to set them as props on the function you will return, but later additions to the prototype will reference them as 'this'. e.g.

```
function F() {
    const f = function() {
        return {};
    }
    f.favoriteBand = 'The Books';
    Object.setPrototypeOf(f, F.prototype);
    return f;
}
F.prototype.getFavoriteBand = function(){ return this.favoriteBand; }

var f = new F();
f.getFavoriteBand() // returns 'The Books'
```

Answer (score -1):

In you your example F is not a constructor it is a function that returns an anonymous constructor which you then call new upon. instanceof works by looking at the prototype chain, so your code doesn't work because you haven't setup up the prototypes correctly.

This [page](http://www.coolpage.com/developer/javascript/Correct%20OOP%20for%20Javascript.html) has a good explain of JavaScript Constructors and how to subsclass.

Take a look at the following code and see if it helps.

```
function F() {
    this.whoami = 'F';
    this.whatami = 'F';

}

function Sub() {
 this.whoami = 'G';
}

Sub.prototype = new F();

function G() {
    return new Sub;
}

var f = new G();
console.log(f instanceof F); // returns false
console.log(f.whoami);
console.log(f.whatami);
​
```