# Call an object as a function?

Tags: javascript

Probably I am reinventing a wheel but I am trying to create a nice logger for myself with coloring.

The idea is to be able to `require` this logger from my components, and upont requiring it pass to it some name, so that if I call a logger from a component, it will output a name of this component (or whatever text I pass it to).

So my module looks like this:

```
var chalk = require("chalk");

var JustLogger = function(name) {
   this.name = name;
};

// message types
JustLogger.prototype.error = function() {
   return console.log(this.greet(chalk.red) + chalk.red.apply(null, arguments));
};

JustLogger.prototype.info = function() {
   return console.log(this.greet(chalk.cyan) + chalk.cyan.apply(null, arguments));
};

// coloring
JustLogger.prototype.green = function() {
   return chalk.green.apply(this, arguments);
};

// utility
JustLogger.prototype.greet = function(f) {
   return f(chalk.bold("[" + this.name["0"] + "]: "));
};

const _instance = function(){
   return new JustLogger(arguments);
};
module.exports = _instance;
```

So there's a logger object created, and a couple of prototypes as well to assist it - in that way we won't pollute memory when we'll instantiate this logger in 10 different components.

It works just great, if I use it like this:

```
var logger = require(path_to_just_logger)("some name");
logger.error("this is an error message"); // outputs in red [some name]: this is an error message
logger.info("this is an info message"); // outputs in cyan [some name]: this is an info message
```

But is it possible to make it so that it would be possible to do this as well:

```
var logger = require(path_to_just_logger)("some name");
logger.error("this is an error message"); // outputs in red [some name]: this is an error message
logger.info("this is an info message"); // outputs in cyan [some name]: this is an info message
logger("this is default message"); // should output `[some name]:this is default message` with no colors
```

The idea here that the logger may output special type of messages like `.error` or `.info` by calling appropriate method if I need to, but it should just do a simple `console.log` or output in white if I just pass a string to it after instantiation.

I am feeling that there should be a hack to do it.

Comment: You can return a function and assign the new 'methods' on them

Comment: Functions are objects. Functions can have properties. As long as `logger` is a function, this can work just fine.

Comment: Maybe this could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341127/can-javascript-constructor-return-function-and-keep-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects with a special internal tag of `[[call]]` which means they can be called as functions.

It's perfectly acceptable in JavaScript to assign methods onto a function, and it's a pattern that's often used.

Comment: so in my case what shall I add to my logger code so that I would be able to use `logger("blablabla")` after instantiation?